# Oracle Text truncate words to 64 CHARS but token limit is 64 BYTES

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, oracle-text

I'm using Oracle 19c.

I have a table with a VARCHAR2(4000) column for which I'm creating a full-text index using Oracle Text.

The SQL creating the index is as follow:

```sql
begin
ctx_ddl.create_index_set('ix_iset');
ctx_ddl.create_preference('ix_pref', 'BASIC_LEXER');
ctx_ddl.set_attribute('ix_pref', 'skipjoins', '-');
ctx_ddl.set_attribute ( 'ix_pref', 'index_stems', 'portuguese');
ctx_ddl.set_attribute ( 'ix_pref', 'index_text', 'YES');
ctx_ddl.set_attribute ( 'ix_pref', 'base_letter', 'YES');
end;

CREATE INDEX ix_tx_column ON MYTABLE(tx_column)
INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXCAT
PARAMETERS ('index set ix_iset lexer ix_pref');
```

Everything works very well, but when there is a word with more than 64 chars, an error is raised:

```
ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text Error:
DRG-50857: oracle error in dreii1fsh
ORA-12899: value too large for column "CAD"."DR$IX_TX_COLUMN$I"."DR$TOKEN" (actual: 65, maximum: 64)


ORA-06512: em "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 186
ORA-06512: em "CTXSYS.CATINDEXMETHODS", line 102
29855. 00000 -  "error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine"
*Cause:    Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.
*Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly.
```

I've looked into the documentation and the only reference to this limitation is this item:
[2.14 Token Limitations for Oracle Text Indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ccref/oracle-text-indexing-elements.html#GUID-07C6FA15-3FBE-499B-8318-73F4B1190B19)

After some research I realized that probably the Oracle-Text internal functions are truncating the words to 64 **CHARS**, but the token limit is 64 **BYTES**.

The text word causing this error have Diacritical Characters within its first 64 chars like ç ã õ é and so on... Each char are 2 bytes in size.

I tried to set `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=BYTE` with no success.

As long as I researched, there is no way how to change the size of the index token.

---

Edit:
The result of `SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters` is:

[image]

Comment: Did you try with AUTO_LEXER?

Comment: @davidm I tried AUTO_LEXER and the result is the same

Comment: Please check this [link](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/mc9j61hrc2crtda3wvs0ct6us) and confirm it is a valid example. This one works.

Comment: Also post the result of this query `SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters`

Comment: @davidm I run the script (at this [link](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/mc9j61hrc2crtda3wvs0ct6us)) until the CREATE INDEX intruction, when it breaks with the same error described in the original question.

Comment: @davidm, added the result of  `SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters`

Comment: Can you detect the string which causes the error?

Comment: There are several strings that causes the error, pretty much like your example. I'm reproducing it in development with the string (look the 4th char) "qweçqweqweqqweqweqweqqweqweqweqqweqweqweqqweqweqweqqweqweqweqqweqweqweq"